# Android calendar get previous to previous month of previous year

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am facing issue with android calendar, I want to get previous to previous month, when i am trying it with current year this will achieve my goal, but when i am trying with previous year it fails. in my case today is 29/apr/2020 and i want feb/2019 return from calendar. please help me with this.

my code is following

````
Date dt = new Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(dt);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 2; // beware of month indexing from zero
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1;
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            String formatMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").format(cal.getTime());
            String formatYear = new SimpleDateFormat("yy").format(cal.getTime());```
````

Comment: What is the output?

Answer (score 1):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

Allow me to suggest that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work.

```
    YearMonth currentMonth = YearMonth.of(2020, Month.APRIL);
    YearMonth backThen = currentMonth.minusYears(1).minusMonths(2);

    String formatMonth = backThen.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM"));
    String formatYear = backThen.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy"));

    System.out.printf("Month %s; year %s%n", formatMonth, formatYear);
```

Output on my computer is (locale dependent):

> Month feb.; year 19

For the sake of a reproducible example I hardcoded the year and month. To start from the current month in some time zone use something like this:

```
    YearMonth currentMonth = YearMonth.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Minsk"));
```

### What went wrong in your code?

It’s the poor and confusing design of the `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar` classes.

You said you ran your code on 29/apr/2020. This causes your `Calendar` to be set back to 29th February 2019. This date does not exist; there were only 28 days in February last year. Instead `Calendar` picks the day after February 28, that is, March 1. Causing you to get an incorrect month.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.